# use a dictionary to change element text in xml

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, iteration

I am attempting to learn python while also saving myself a lot of work.

I have an xml file and a dictionary file mapping old to new device id's.

I am trying to either iterate through the tree and for any logical_devid children that match the dictionary key OR for each dictionary key find the corresponding logical_devid.  In either case replacing the logical_devid.text with it's new value.

e.g. xml snippet

```
<lun>
   <pseudo_dev>emcpower146a</pseudo_dev>
   <udev>0x12b00000490</udev>
   <product_id>symmetrix</product_id>
   <frame_id>000192604705</frame_id>
   <logical_devid_type>symm_id</logical_devid_type>
   <logical_devid>0A43</logical_devid>
 </lun>
```

Text file of

```
0A40   0127
0A41   0128
0A42   0129
0A43   012A
```

I have loaded the xml file as an ElementTree object and I've loaded the text file into a dictionary.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='emcpower.mappings')
d = {}
with open("translate-table.txt") as f: 
    for line in f: 
        (old, new) = line.split() 
        d[(old)] = new
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out the best way to iterate and replace the elem.text 
I think the best way is to iterate through the known changes in the dictionary.

```
for old_devid, new_devid in d.iteritems():
```

and then do some sort of xml find for child logical_devid that matches the old_devid, setting elem.text to new_devid

Here is the full script that does pretty much what I want:
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
try:
        import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#read in emcpower.mappings file as an entire xml tree of elements
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='emcpower.mappings')

# this defines a dictionary with the contents of the translate table which
# is simply the old device ID as key and new device id as value

d = {}
with open("translate-table.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
                (old, new) = line.split()
                d[(old)] = new

for elem in tree.iterfind('lun/logical_devid'):
        old_devid = elem.text
        new_devid = d.get(old_devid)
        try:
                new_devid
        except NameError:
                new_devid = None
        else:
                if new_devid:
                        elem.text = new_devid
                        print "The logical_devid will be changed to", elem.text



tree.write('emcpower.mappings.new', )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would make more sense to iterate through the `tree` and see if each `logical_devid` is in `d`.  Once you have the `logical_devid` in a variable (say, `old_devid`), then:

```
new_devid = d.get(old_devid)
```

will see if you have a replacement.  If `new_devid is null` then it's not in the dictionary.  Otherwise, `new_devid` should replace the current value of `logical_devid` in the tree.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense.